# combination of advanced indexing and basic slicing

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to understand [combination of basic slicing and advanced indexing section](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing) from Numpy docs. It says that advanced indexing operation may have different memory layout, **but** I observed some different behaviors in the code snippet below:

```
a = np.random.randn(3,3)
# case1
a[:, :][a > 0] = 0
output:
array([[ 0.        , -1.07474179, -0.06313855],
       [ 0.        , -0.74049837, -1.7376245 ],
       [-0.93616586,  0.        , -2.2520479 ]])
# case2
a[:, (0, 1, 2)][a > 0] = 0
output:
array([[ 0.67667783, -1.07474179, -0.06313855],
       [ 0.74418166, -0.74049837, -1.7376245 ],
       [-0.93616586,  0.96351976, -2.2520479 ]])
```

In my view, the second case is advanced indexing, so the modification will no be performed on the original `a`. (If I misunderstand it, correct me please.)

**But**, the following case seems that the key is not the advanced indexing.

```
a[:, (0, 1, 2)] = 0
output:
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

It confused me a lot, could you give me some ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: a[:,:] does nothing except make view of the whole array,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case #2, `a[:, (0, 1, 2)][a > 0] = 0`, advanced indexing is creating a copy of the array, as explained in the [NumPy manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

> Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data

The assignment operation then changes this copy, which means that the original array `a` is left unchanged. The copy is triggered by the `[a<0]`, which causes the interpreter to call `a.__getitem__((slice(None,None), (0, 1, 2)))` which results in a copy.

In the third case, `a[:, (0, 1, 2)] = 0`, the interpreter doesn't need to create a copy. Instead, it calls `a.__setitem__((slice(None,None), (0, 1, 2)), 0)` which directly modifies the original array.

This behavior is explained in The NumPy Cookbook in the entry "[But fancy indexing does seem to return views sometimes, doesn't it?](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html#But-fancy-indexing-does-seem-to-return-views-sometimes,-doesn't-it?)"